# Include ToString in Interface C#

Tags: c#, interface, tostring

When I'm adding `ToString` to my interface I don't get any warning or potential fixes (VS2022).

As far as I know, every object has `ToString` so it would be redundant to include it in any interface?

So I'm curious if these two interfaces are different and if there is ever a use case for including `ToString`.

```
public interface IFoe
{
    int Damage { get; }
}

public interface IFoe
{
    int Damage { get; }
    string ToString();
}
```

Comment: If used that, it would be a complete waste of a line code and a handful of printable characters. :)

Answer (score 2):

They are different. You can explicitly implement `IFoe.ToString()`:

```
class MyClass : IFoe
{
    ...
    string IFoe.ToString() => "a";
    public override string ToString() => "b";
}
```

Calling `((IFoe)myClassInstance).ToString()` would then return `a`.

I doubt there is any practical use, and it only adds confusion.

Comment: This means the same class can provide different implementations for properties and methods even if they have the same name. Based on which interface that calls on them?

Comment: *Based on which interface that calls on them?* - this is a bit of a weird way to phrase it, as interfaces don't call things.. an interface represents something that an object could "be treated like". A Tiger can implement IAnimal, and when you have a method that can operate on any IAnimal, a Tiger can "be treated like" an IAnimal because it has all the necessary properties and actions that make it possible to consider it an IAnimal (number of legs, ability to eat.. etc). It's unlikely in most cases that you'd want a Tiger to appear or behave differently when it's being treated as an IAnimal

Comment: Agree that the phrase was confusing! But you can say that a class is called through an interface? Tiger is called through the interface IAnimal.